# Getting CSS Values from elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, local-storage, web-storage

I need to use the web storage api to store style changes of the elements on one page. 
I actually have no clue how to do this but I thought I'd start by getting the CSS attribute that's  *been changed* and storing it in an array. Im trying to follow what's going [here](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-two/) and tailoring it to my problem.

this is what i've tried in order to get the values but im not sure if it's correct:

```
function newItem(){
    var bgImg = document.getElementsByTagName('body').bgImg[0].style.getPropertyValue('background');
    var wideScreen = getElementById('sidebar').style.getPropertyValue('display');
    var playerColor = getElementById('video_container').style.getPropertyValue('background-color');     
    }
```

I am not sure if the code i've written above grabs the information I need.

Comment: Why are you not sure?  Have you not tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle().`

`getComputedStyle()` gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element.

```
var element = document.getElementById('sidebar'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    display = style.getPropertyValue('display');


var element = document.getElementById('video_container'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    bg = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
```